# Bash scripting: How can I patch files? (write a given string in a given position of a file)

Tags: bash, scripting, file, patch

I’m writing a script to change the UUID of an NTFS partition (AFAIK, there is none). That means writing 8 bytes from 0x48 to 0x4F (72-79 decimal) of `/dev/sdaX` (X being the # of my partition).

If I wanted to change it to a random UUID, I could use this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdaX bs=8 count=1 seek=9 conv=notrunc
```

Or I could change `/dev/urandom` to `/dev/sdaY` to clone the UUID from another partition.

But... what if I want to craft a personalized UUID? I already have it stored (and regex-checked) in a `$UUID` variable in hexadecimal string format (16 characters), like this:

```
UUID="2AE2C85D31835048"
```

I was thinking about this approach:

```
echo "$UUID" | xxd -r -p | dd of=/dev/sdaX ...
```

This is just a scratch... I’m not sure about the exact options to make it work. My question is:

- Is the `echo $var | xxd -r | dd` really the best approach?
- What would be the exact command and options to make it work?

As for the answers, I’m also looking for:

- An explanation of all the options used, and what they do.
- If possible, an alternative command to test it in a file and/or screen before changing the partition.

I already have an 100-byte dump file called *ntfs.bin* that I can use for tests and check results using

```
xxd ntfs.bin
```

So any solution that provides me a way to check results using `xxd` in screen so I can compare with original *ntfs.bin* file would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick question here, you've tested this `dd` against your device with success?  Your `echo ... dd` pipeline should work, as it will read stdin should `if=` not be named.

Comment: Well, ive tested dd if=/dev/urandom against my ntfs.bin file. It worked fine (ive edited my post to add the conv=notrunc option). But my fear is: /dev/urandom has infinite bytes, and my echo have only 16. When seek is used, does it seek both output AND input? How to specify "read the WHOLE input, but seek ONLY the output" ? Shall i use "seek" or "skip" ? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UUID="2AE2C85D31835048"
echo "$UUID" | xxd -r -p | wc -c
echo "$UUID" | xxd -r -p | dd of=file obs=1 oseek=72 conv=block,notrunc cbs=8
```

Comment: Hi! The 2nd command (wc -c) outputted 8. Whats that for? The last command has error in **oseek**, but after replacing it to **seek**, it seemed to work fine in my test files. Care to explain the options and values used? What are they for, and why such values? Thanks!