# Script command to manipulate binary file (on linux)

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking for a mechanism to manipulate my eeprom image with a unique device id. I'd like to do this in a make file so that the device would automatically obtain a new ID and then update it to the data image, then flash it. In pseudocode:

```
wget http://my.centralized.uid.service/new >new.id
binedit binary.image -write 0xE6 new.id
flash binary.image into device
```

So first we get an id into a separate file, then we overwrite the image (from given offset) with the contents of this ID file. Then flash. But how to do the second part? I looked up *bvi*, which seems to have some scripting abilities, but I did not fully understand it, and to be honest vi always gave me the creeps.

Thanks for help beforehand!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Scripting: How to patch files? (write a given string in a given position of a file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196096/bash-scripting-how-to-patch-files-write-a-given-string-in-a-given-position-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I made the initial vote to close as a duplicate. This answer is adapted from the referenced question.)

Use `dd` with the `notrunc` option:

```
offset=$(( 0xe6 ))
length=$( wc -c < new.id )
dd bs=1 if=new.id of=binary.image count=$length seek=$offset conv=notrunc
```

You may want to try this on a copy first, just to make sure it works properly.

Comment: You are right, is a duplicate. I did not include "patching" in original keyword searches. And the answer is exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the offset of the file that you want to replace from, you can use the [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command to split the initial file up until the offset. The [`cat`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) command can then be used to join the required pieces together.

Another useful tool when working with binary files is [`od`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od) which will let you examine the binary files in human readable format.

Comment: mm, the split/cat solution is quite innovative, never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps use something like `Perl`. See [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/cookbook/chapter/ch08.html) and in particular the section labelled *Updating a Random-Access File* (example [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/cookbook/chapter/ch08.html#24725))